# get current MetadataPath C# change connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I use this code to change Connection string

```
var connstring = ConfigurationManager
                 .ConnectionStrings["BAEntities"].ConnectionString;
var estringnew = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connstring);
estringnew.Metadata = Properties.Settings.Default.MetadataFilePath; 
var context = new BAEntities(estringnew.ToString());
var query =
    from con in context.Contacts
    where con.Addresses.Any((a) => a.City == "Seattle")
    select con;
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx)

I have error in line:

```
estringnew.Metadata = Properties.Settings.Default.MetadataFilePath;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Settings' does not contain a definition for
>   'MetadataPath' and no extension method 'MetadataPath' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Settings' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

how can i find the current `MetadataFilePath` in the project?

I use Entity framework 6 and .net 4.5

Comment: is this code first or database first?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Database first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your model is named `Abc` then set the `Metadata` like this:

```
estringnew.Metadata = "res://*/Abc.csdl|res://*/Abc.ssdl|res://*/Abc.msl"
```

In the above you will see the wildcard `*` used. Here is the meaning of that:

> If you specify a wildcard (*) for assemblyFullName, the Entity Framework runtime will search for resources in the following locations, in this order:

1. The calling assembly.
2. The referenced assemblies.
3. The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.

**A Better Option**

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAEntities"].ConnectionString;
Type contextType = typeof(BAEntities);
string efConnection = 
    string.Format(
        "metadata=res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"{1}\"",
        contextType.Name,
        con);

object objContext = Activator.CreateInstance(contextType, efConnection);
return objContext as Entities;
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings)